# How to allow the app importing my package (library) to create new localization of my package?

Tags: swift, package, localization, multiplatform

So I am developing a multiplatform library in Swift.

The package (library) is using several different string literals for error messages etc. so I would like to allow their localization.

So when an app (it should be multiplatform, so created by `swift package init --type executable`) depends on/imports my package, it should be possible for the app to define new localization for the strings in my library.

I tried to use the `NSLocalizedString` for this. So I created a file `en.lproj/Localizable.strings` in `Sources` of my library and set the `defaultLocalization: "en"` in the `Package.swift` file. Then I replaced the strings with this extension:

```
extension String {
    internal static func localized(_ key: String, comment: String) -> String {
        for bundle in Bundle.allBundles + Bundle.allFrameworks + [Bundle.module] {
            let string = String(NSLocalizedString(key, bundle: bundle, comment: comment))
            if string != key {
                return string
            }
        }
        return key
    }
}
```

The idea was that if the app then defines its own `de.lproj/Localizable.strings` in its own `Sources` containing the keys from my library and has `defaultLocalization: "de"` set, the strings in my library would be localized using this `de` localization in the app.

This did not work.

My other idea is to create a `public` `class`/`struct`/`enum`, that will contain `static` property for all of the strings in my library. Therefore the app could set all of them at will. Something like:

```
public enum Localization {
    public enum Error {
        public static var common = "Default error message"
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

While this would probably work, I wonder:

**Is there a better way to do it?**

Also the `LocalizedStringResource` doesn't seem to be an option, because it is not present on all platforms.